# Flickr links are not working on HTML page

Tags: html

I have some images on flickr and was trying to link them to an webpage using just html.

This is the code:

```html
<p>
  <img src="https://flic.kr/p/2j7YQHd">
</p>

<p>
  <img src="https://flic.kr/p/2j83Toz" width="100px" height="100px">
</p>

<p>
  <img src="https://flic.kr/p/2j7YSnF" width="100px" height="100px">
</p>

<p>
  <img src="https://flic.kr/p/2j7YSyh" width="100px" height="100px">
</p>
```

But these images don't load at all. So can anyone give me a solution?

Comment: In your HTML attributes, I would remove the spaces around the `=` signs, and also the commas after the `width` attributes as these are unnecessary. If there's still a problem, then this is not to do with HTML. but the links themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs to be a direct link to the image! Try:

```html
<p>
  <img src="https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/49962103478_924be0cc98_b.jpg">
</p>
<p>
  <img src="https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/49962892937_b71b5d5054_h.jpg" width="100px" height="100px">
</p>
<p>
  <img src="https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/49962109073_dab100e634_b.jpg" width="100px" height="100px">
</p>
<p>
  <img src="https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/49962109688_685848760f_c.jpg" width="100px" height="100px">
</p>
```

For further reference, you don't really need the commas between attributes or the spaces between the `=` and `""`.

Also, if you need to find a direct link to the image, use the inspect element tool on your browser to open up your browser's Developer Tools panel. Here, you can find the section that deals with the images you need, which you can usually identify with the `<img>` tag. For example, in the case of your first image, you can find the direct link underlined and highlighted in blue here:

[image: Developer Tools]

With Flickr, credit to the person who posted the content is actually given in its `alt` attribute, so you could optionally add `alt="Elon-Musk-On-Perception | by kawshikbss"` just in case an image can't be displayed.

Comment: Thank you very much it helped and my code works now.